# Is there a way to get a webhook called on every Firebase Realtime DB transaction?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Basically, I'm using Firebase as my realtime database from my iOS application. However, I'd love to get a "Transaction log" to my server, even if it is not realtime. Is there a way to set this up? Maybe with a webhook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) to write a [database trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) that runs some JavaScript (running in a node.js environment) whenever data in your database changes.  You can effectively use this to send changes from your Realtime Database to whatever other server you control.  You would probably have to implement a webhook or some other endpoint on your server to receive the data.

In order to make outbound network requests in a function like this, you will need to upgrade your project to the Blaze plan if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand very well your question, what are you trying to achieve?

You can "save" an action done on your app with firebase in , at least, three ways:

1)Creating a node to log the transactions and use childupdates to save a transaction in its node and at the same time in another node like "transactionsLog" (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#update_specific_fields)

2)If you only need to track events done in your app by users, you can use firebase Analytics and save an event every time there is a transaction: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/start (get started) and https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/start#log_events (to log events)

3)To do more complex actions when a transaction has been done you can use a Firebase Function (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) where you can do, in javascript (it is a nodeJs environment ), everything you want.

Example first method (Swift):

```
    let key = ref.child("transactions").childByAutoId().key
    let post = ["uid": userID,
                "author": username,
                "amount": amount,
                "date": date]
    let childUpdates = ["/transactions/\(key)": post,
                        "/transactionsLog/\(userID)/\(key)/": true]
    ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```